# Absolute Imports in React app WITHOUT create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

There are lots of resources out there explaining how to do absolute imports in React with create-react-app

But I want to add absolute imports to an existing project which wasn't created through create-react-app. Is anyone aware of a guide  for how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it...

But adding aliases in my resolver in webpack.config

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
    }
}
```

Lets me replace imports like this

`import Component from './../../src/Component';`

With this

`import Component from 'src/Component';`

See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/